# Stop Rails Anchor param getting encoded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, anchor, urlencode, kaminari, urldecode

While using Kaminari gem in rails, I got to add an anchor value inorder to load the tabs correctly. But rails encoding the "#" symbol, which preventing the page from rendering correctly. Is there any chance to prevent this from happening.

sample code: `<%= paginate products, params: {anchor: 'tab1'} %>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add your code to the question itself (edit it) rather than in the comments please

Answer (score 0):

URL helpers accept `ahchor` parameter.

`link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, anchor: "wall")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But my scenario is different. I have used anchor param, but now the tag is getting encoded.